# How accelerate an algorithm to find the time overlaps?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, overlap

I have a dataset including 4 attributes :

- an id attribute called "id" (integer)
- an attribute called "group" (integer)
- an admission time called "aankomstdt" (datetime)
- a discharge time called "ontslagdt" (datetime)

The dataset looks like that :

```
id    group          aankomstdt                   ontslagdt
 1   A         Thu Nov 14 04:31:00 CET 2019 Thu Nov 14 09:43:00 CET 2019
 2   A         Thu Nov 14 05:38:00 CET 2019 Thu Nov 14 06:19:00 CET 2019
 3   A         Thu Nov 14 05:52:00 CET 2019 Thu Nov 14 09:14:00 CET 2019
 4   A         Thu Nov 14 05:54:00 CET 2019 Thu Nov 14 10:02:00 CET 2019
 5   B         Thu Nov 14 06:06:00 CET 2019 Thu Nov 14 11:22:00 CET 2019
```

I would like  to calculate the number of examples  that are simultaneously admitted. As such a new attribute should provide me the number of patients admitted for each patient (id) during his/her admission time frame.
I created the following working code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime



admission_time = "aankomstdt"
discharge_time = "ontslagdt"
group = 'group'
date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
path = 'D:/Lionel/Formations_DataScience/Rapidminer/Tests_Rapidminer/count_overlaps_sven.xlsx'


def convert_to_datetime(a) :

  a = datetime.strptime(str(a), date_format)
  return a


def interval_overlaps(a, b):
  return min(a[discharge_time], b[discharge_time]) - max(a[admission_time], b[admission_time]) > np.timedelta64(-1)


def count_overlaps(df1):
  return pd.Series([df1.apply(lambda x: interval_overlaps(x, df1.iloc[i]), axis=1).sum() - 1 for i in range(len(df1))], df1.index)
  #return pd.Series([df1.apply(lambda x: interval_overlaps(x, df1.iloc[i]), axis=1).sum() - 1 for i in range(len(df1))])
def rm_main():

  data = pd.read_excel(path)
  data[admission_time] = data[admission_time].apply(convert_to_datetime)
  data[discharge_time] = data[discharge_time].apply(convert_to_datetime)
  data["count"] = data.groupby(group).apply(count_overlaps).values
  return data
```

But my original dataset has around 70 000 examples, so I estimate that computation time is around 1 month (24h/24).
My question is : Is there a solution in Python to significantly accelerate this algorithm ?

Thanks you,

Comment: The fastest way to find items with the overlapped time is probably to first sort them by begin time (maybe they are already?) and then compare only to items immediately after it (stop at first which does not overlap). I expect that can be done in seconds.

Comment: @zvone, thanks you for your comment. Have you got a working implementation of your idea in Python ?

Answer (score 0):

The classic is when you just want an all time sum.

For recall approach be like:
for each row, consider two events:

- {t: row.startAt, kind: 'start'},
- {t: row.endAt, kind: 'end'}

Make a big array of events and sort them by t asc

```
best = 0
pool = 0
foreach event:
  if event.kind == 'start':
    pool++
    if pool > best
      best = pool
  else
    pool--
```

The maximum of simultaneous visiting patients is stored in best.

Explanation is something like:

- When event starts, we have a new visitor on top of the present ones
- When event ends, a visitor has left the pool.
- We just want to keep track of the length of the pool

In your case, wa can adapt: associate a pool to each patient.

Below consider the patientPool: [patient.id]=>maxVisitors

```
patientPool = {}
pool = 0
foreach event:
  if event.kind == 'start':
    patientPool[event.id] = pool
    pool++
    forall id in patientPool
      if pool > patientPool[id]
        patientPool[id] = pool //eventually think about giving a reference to your row for the count instead..
  else
    pool--
    delete patientPool[event.id]
```

In below implem for illustration purpose (js), 70k rows (random) takes about 15s. For python refer to pseudo algorithm above (which does not differ much)

I have only tested the exactness for the sample below.

```js
let seed = 4;
function random() {
    let x = Math.sin(seed++) * 10000;
    return parseInt((x - Math.floor(x))*1000);
}

let qs = Array(10).fill(0).map(random).reduce((qs, t, i)=>{
  return (i%2 === 0 ? qs.push([{ t, i: i/2 }]) : qs[qs.length - 1].push({ t, i: (i - 1)/2 })), qs
},[]).map(([a,b])=> a.t < b.t ? [{ ...a, open: true }, b] : [{ ...b, open:true}, a])

function go(qs){
  const events = qs.flatMap(x => x).sort((a, b) => a.t - b.t)
  //patients is an array where patients[i] maps to patient.id == i
  const patients = Array(events.reduce((acc,x)=> Math.max(acc, x.i), 0) + 1)
  const patientPool = new Set
  let pool = 0
  events.forEach(ev => {
    if (ev.open) {
      if (!patientPool.has(ev.i)) {
        patients[ev.i] = pool
        patientPool.add(ev.i)
      }
      pool++
      for(let patientI of patientPool){
        if (pool > patients[patientI]) {
          patients[patientI] = pool
        }
      }
    } else {
      pool--
      patientPool.delete(ev.i)
    }
  })
  return patients
}
console.time('disp')
const res = go(qs)
console.log('go', qs, res)
console.timeEnd('disp')
```